# Input and Output Impedances of Single to Differential mode converter

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, impedance, differential, single-ended

I have this circuit that converts a single ended input signal to differential output signal. I want to understand how to calculate or find out its input and output impedances?

The two op-amps are in inverting and non-inverting configuration. Will this circuit work correctly as single to differential mode converter or should both of the op-amps be in the same configuration?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: what range of frequencies must you handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're driving the circuit with.  Your noninverting arm has infinite input impedance, and your inverting arm has relatively small input impedance.  This could be problematic, but not in every situation.  For example, if your input is some sort of piezo-device, you will be very unhappy.

The input impedance of the inverting input is \$330R \parallel 660R\$.  The output impedances are small, approximately \$33R\$ on each branch.

Comment: How can we do it with both non-inverting arms?

Comment: For one, you can use a voltage follower to buffer \$V_{\text{in}}\$

Comment: You need at least one stage that INVERTS.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf after you buffer Vin, it doesn't make as much difference what happens.  A voltage follower on the far left wire fixes most ills.